# How to type a dynamic cell reference into a formula?

Tags: excel, function

I have a excel sheet that uses a macro to add a new row and copies all the formulas down.  I am currently using the AverageIf function to take the average of a column that is within a percent of another cell.  What I currently have is `AverageIf(J11:J11),"<"O1)`  This works fine for Cell J11 but it doesn't update the range to (J11:J12) when a new row is added.  Is there a way to type the second J11 so it will become a dynamic reference cell or is that not possible outside of a macro?

Comment: If you used an Excel Table it would automatically expand. Or you could use a dynamic named range but that is probably overkill.

Comment: This formula that is in my macro that has a dynamic cell reference.   =((130-(H16))/$H$7)-('Build Information'!$F$6-(C16)).  I achieve this by using {Cells(7, 6).Formula = "=((130-(H" & y & "))/$H$7)-('Build Information'!$F$6-(C" & y & "))"}.  Im assuming you mean there is no way to achieve the first formula without it being made in a macro?

Comment: The dynamic name range maybe the way to go.  I will look into it further.  Thanks